# Autoplaying Video element from Javascript does not work on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, mobile-safari

I'm trying to get video stream from phone camera and display the stream on a video element. This is the gist of the code I have:

```
    ...
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream)=>{
        video.srcObject=stream;
        video.volume=0;
        video.mute=0;
        video.play(); //error here on  iOS Safari
        ...
```

While this works on *all* desktop and android browsers, this does not seem to work on iOS, giving me the error on line `video.play()`.

From what I understand so far, this seems to be a [safety measure by Safari on mobile](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html) to prevent websites from consuming too much of user's data. Meaning, unless specifically initiated by the user, the browser won't allow `video.play()`

I have tried adding "`muted`" attribute on the video element itself (besides just `autoplay`), but that did not seem to fix the issue.

So, I'd like to know if there are any other remedies to the issue here or if I should look for alternative ways to show the video feed. Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried adding `playsinline` to the video element?

https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: My hero!.......